# Joomla List All Categories

Tags: view, joomla, categories

I use for a menu-item the style "List All Categories".

I want to edit the code, however I cannot find this file anywhere!

I supposed it should be in components/com_content/views/category but no file I find there seems to be related to the html output.

This is an example of the HTML output:

```
<div class="categories-list">
                                                                            <div class="category-item first">
                    <h3 class="page-header item-title"><a
                href="/joomla/index.php/browse/8-eat-meet">
                EAT&amp;MEET</a>
                                        </h3>
                        <img src="/joomla/images/cat1.jpg"/>


    </div>
            <div class="category-item">
                    <h3 class="page-header item-title"><a
                href="/joomla/index.php/browse/9-dreaming">
                DREAMING</a>
                                        </h3>
                        <img src="/joomla/images/cat2.jpg"/>


    </div>
```

Does anyone know where I can find this file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That's because categories are generally attached to existing extensions, the majority use case being articles.  My assumption here is these are the categories you are referring to.  If you selected the "List all categories" menu option from the Articles sub-group, then the assumption is correct.  The path is:

components/com_content/views/categories/tmpl

If you would like to change these files, I HIGHLY recommend not editing the core files but using template overrides to customize.  See link below for specifics.

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I have checked all files in that folder (and also folder "category") but nothing resembles the code I've showed above.

Answer (score 1):

If it is the categorIES layout that you want that will be in the `components/com_content/views/categories/tmpl` categories folder (I'm assuming you are talking about in the front end).
The layout files are in the tmpl folder.

In Joomla 3.2 you will find that these files reference the files `layouts/content/categories_default.php` and `layouts/content/categories_default_items.php`. 
This is because the core layouts are the same for all categories (and they can be used by any component that uses categories).

You can override both the tmpl files and the layouts in the html folder of your template.

Update
Here is the code block in the categories_default_items layout that produces the title, image and description HTML

```
    <h3 class="page-header item-title">
        <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($item->id));?>">
        <?php echo $this->escape($item->title); ?></a>
        <?php if ($this->params->get('show_cat_num_articles_cat') == 1) :?>
            <span class="badge badge-info tip hasTooltip" title="<?php echo JHtml::tooltipText('COM_CONTENT_NUM_ITEMS'); ?>">
                <?php echo $item->numitems; ?>
            </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (count($item->getChildren()) > 0) : ?>
            <a href="#category-<?php echo $item->id;?>" data-toggle="collapse" data-toggle="button" class="btn btn-mini pull-right"><span class="icon-plus"></span></a>
        <?php endif;?>
    </h3>
    <?php if ($this->params->get('show_description_image') && $item->getParams()->get('image')) : ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $item->getParams()->get('image'); ?>"/>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($this->params->get('show_subcat_desc_cat') == 1) :?>
        <?php if ($item->description) : ?>
            <div class="category-desc">
                <?php echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', $item->description, '', 'com_content.categories'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry it's not there.

Comment: There are np files in your tmpl folder and no files with those names in your layouts folder?

Comment: There are, but I have checked every file and changes I make are not reflected in the html output

Comment: Where are you making changes? What kind of changes?

Comment: Does this url help? index.php?option=com_content&view=categories&id=0&Itemid=110

It is not overwritten by the template, I have checked that.

Changes in the html, minor changes to see if I see any changes occuring in the source.

Comment: OH you are attempting to override it? Are you doing that with an override in /html/layouts or in html/com_content? Can you give an example of the changes you have made?

Comment: Yes, just minor changes such as changing the name of the css class in the div or something like that. But all these changes are not reflected in the html output.

But if I use another template, it turns out to be the file categories/default.php. But I use a t3 framework blank template and then it doesn't work that way...

Comment: Oh .. you left out crucial information is that you are not using the core.   You need to talk to the t3 people.

Comment: Thanks for your message.

I have figured it out. If I manually override the templates that come with Joomla (e.g. Beez3) there is no problem at all. If I do this manually with the T3 framework template nothing happens at all.

If I override the category/default.php using Joomla backend (Template manager -> bs3_blank_template) Joomla creates the override automatically and turns out, then it does work!

Thanks for your help so far, appreciate it.